# Trigger not firing (compiles successfully)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have these two tables

```
CREATE TABLE Car_Makers ( 
ID NUMBER(5), 
Maker VARCHAR2(15), 
FullName VARCHAR2(25), 
Country NUMBER(5),
MODAL_TOTALS INT, 
CONSTRAINT car_maker_country_id_fk FOREIGN KEY(Country) REFERENCES 
 Countries(CountryID), 
CONSTRAINT car_maker_id PRIMARY KEY(ID) 
 );

CREATE TABLE Model_Details ( 
ModelID NUMBER(5), 
Maker NUMBER(5), 
Model VARCHAR2(25), 
CONSTRAINT model_unique UNIQUE(Model), 
CONSTRAINT model_details_id_pk PRIMARY KEY(ModelID), 
CONSTRAINT model_maker_fk FOREIGN KEY(Maker) REFERENCES Car_Makers(ID) 
);
```

I want to create a trigger that will update `MODEL_TOTALS` IN `Car_Makers` WHEN a new row is inserted in `Model_Details`. However my triggers runs successfully but is not firing. I don't get any error but when i insert a row in `Model_details` the corresponding `MODEL_TOTAL` value doesn't update. Any help will be appreciated, here is my trigger

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_modeltotals_up 
   AFTER INSERT ON MODEL_DETAILS
   REFERENCING NEW AS NEWROW
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
   UPDATE CAR_MAKERS SET MODEL_TOTALS = MODEL_TOTALS+1 WHERE 
   CAR_MAKERS."ID" = :NEWROW.MAKER;
    END;
```

Comment: I might add that trying to maintain some sort of running total like this is fundamentally flawed.  All you are doing, really is keeping a count of rows in the primary table.  A fundamental rule is never store what can be computed at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, `null`s are causing the issue. Add a `coalesce` in your update

```
UPDATE CAR_MAKERS SET MODAL_TOTALS = COALESCE(MODAL_TOTALS,0) +1 WHERE 
   CAR_MAKERS."ID" = :NEWROW.MAKER;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b91882141058005337a558d5fde8ecb7)

Answer (score 1):

you trigger is not valid because, you made a mistake . The column is **MODAL**_TOTALS and not **MODEL**_TOTALS

So that the column `MODAL_TOTALS` always get a value in `Car_Makers` you can addthe a `not null` constraint or maybe set a default value to 0

```
MODAL_TOTALS INT not null,
```

or

```
MODAL_TOTALS INT Default 0,
```